# Pig: How to use a library from Piggybank

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to use a library from Piggybank and it's giving me some errors.

This is my code:

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage; 
a = LOAD 'csvtest/' USING CSVExcelStorage()
```

And the errors:

```
2015-09-15 00:18:15,480 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 101: file '/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar' does not exist.
```

I followed the instructions from this guide, [PiggyBank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank), and already built the project.

Should I move `piggybank.jar` to `/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
REGISTER <path of piggybank jar>;
```

You need you specify the path of the jar in your local system where you have extracted the pig.

For example this the path for me:

```
/Users/username/pig-0.13.0/lib/piggybank.jar
```

Comment: @user3276768 did this help you? Please accept, if yes.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar trouble where I used: REGISTER 'hdfs:///usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar'